# Windows Batch Script- for /D delims Executing Multiple times

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, break

I am trying to set up a batch backup script on Win7. It is mostly working, but I have a line of code executing multiple times. I've done some searching around and I think it has to do with how batch files handle code in "( )" but I'm not sure the best way to fix it.

Any help would be awesome!

Script:

```
for /D %%d in (C:\toBackupDir\*.*) do (
 for %%f in (C:\zipDir\*) do (
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%i in ("%%~nf") do (
    if "%%i"=="%%~nd" (
     if "%%~tf"=="%%~td" (
      echo "%%~nf" is "%%~nd" No Backup necessary.
     ) else (
      7z.exe a -tzip -stl -mx=1     "C:\zipDir\%%~nd_%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~7,2%.zip" "%%d"
     )
    )
  )
 )
)
```

The line "7z.exe" is executed many times if "%%i"=="%%~nd" is true. My thought is that last for loop to split the file name is being executed many times, but once it gets %i and does the comparisons, I'm done with it. Can I break out of the loop once the "7z.exe" line is executed? I've read that breaking out in a batch file is tricky.

Let me know if you need a breakdown of the code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure of `if "%%~tf"=="%%~td" (` - that is, comparing the filetime to the backup directory time? Since you are creating files in `c:\zipdir`, its time will change every time a `7z` instance is invoked. Perhaps it's too late for me - but I lose track of quite what you're attempting to do. A few comments (remember `REM` comments in code blocks, not `::` comments) may explain a lot - and would probably help with future maintenance.

Comment: We don't really need a breakdown of the code, what we need is an overview of the task you are trying to perform and what is happening in relation to those expectations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that normally I cant do that compare. I only posted the part of the script that I was having trouble with. I am running FolderTimeUpdate b4 running this part of the script on temp files. FolderTimeUpdate scans all of the files in each directory and updates the parent folders' Timestamp to that of the oldest file in a child dir. 7-Zip is also setting it's timestamp to the oldest folder with the -stl switch. This works as long as there are no empty folders and if I clean out Zips manually. The script still needs work... but this is where I am currently stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You also test every directory against every zip file.
These are more than 60000 compares with 250 directories and the matching zips. But this is not necessary at all. Then you can not against the time of the folder Compare - it does not update itself. The output from the DIR is therefore not at all suitable.
In addition - what is already with the existing zip fuses, these are also compared each time with. So with two backups of a folder, your batch would always make a new backup.
Your simple loop, which searches for the zipfiles, is practically not finished, because always new files are entered in the MFT and the loop this after the creation issues.

I've taken robocopy to list the files, because this time stamp is very well suited for comparison.
First, only the folder is checked and with it the appropriate zip file. The folder is checked recursively for the files as well as the appropriate zip file. The time stamps are placed in a list and sorted. The loop sets the last value so, if the last (ie the newest) file comes from the folder of the zips does not need a backup.
A suitable time stamp for the file name is also generated.

You may need to adjust the paths.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "Folder=d:\toBackup"
set "Backup=d:\zipdir"
call :TAB
set "TS=."
for /d %%F in ("D:\files\*")do (
  set "TsFn="
  set "tozip="
  for /f "tokens=2,3delims=%TAB%" %%A in ('
    ( robocopy /L "%backup%" ".. only listing ..\\" "%%~nF_*.zip" /njh /fp /ts /ns /nc /ndl /njs ^
    ^& robocopy /L /e "%%F" ".. List only ..\\" /njh /fp /ts /ns /nc /ndl /njs ^)^|sort
  ')do ( 
    set "TsFn=%%A*%%~dpB"
    if /i "%%~dpB"=="%Backup%\" ( set "tozip="
    )else set "tozip=1"
  )
  if defined tozip call :timestamp
  if defined TsFn (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=1-3delims=*" %%S in ("!TS!*!TsFn!")do (
      endlocal
      if NOT defined tozip ( echo  %%T  %%~nxF  - No Backup necessary.
      )else echo 7z.exe a -tzip -stl -mx=1 "%Backup%\%%~nF_%%S.zip" "%%F"
    )
  )
)
pause
exit /b

:TAB
for /f "delims= " %%T in ('robocopy /L . . /njh /njs') do set "TAB=%%T"
 rem END TAB
exit /b

:Timestamp
 rem robocopy /L "\.. Timestamp ..\\" .
for /f "eol=D tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%T in (' robocopy /L  /njh "\|" .^|find "123" ') do (
  set "TS=%%T%%U%%V-%%W%%X%%Y"
  set "TSDATE=%%T%%U%%V"
  set /a YY=%%T , MM=100%%U %%100 , TT=100%%V %%100
)
 rem END Timestamp
exit /b
```

If there is not yet a zip file from the matching folder is available, of course, a zip is created.

A complete backup program
[robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

Comment: Wow pieh- Thankyou! Also, ty for noting the holes in my script. I was actually aware; I was forcing the folder timestamp with another program, and was just manually removing Zips as needed to prevent the issue you were talking about if there were 2 zips. I was planning on attacking that after I had this issue resolved. It looks like youre solving this with "enabledelayedexpansion." I started down that path, but didn't realize you could just set it within an if statement and then I got lost. I'm new to scripting. I'll probably just end up using your code... but I'll comb through it first.